Why using else if instead of if here when building a binary tree?
When building the insertion function in binary tree, I use two if statement to track the node( if the value is smaller than the current node,go left;if bigger,go right) .
I know the difference between else if and if before. So initially the result I suppose is both fine with else if and with if in this condition.
I choose if. But eventually it turns out it only works for else if. When using if result shows segmentation fault. Or sometimes the terminal just doesn't show anything.
Here is the code segment that is correct, the incorrect version changes the elseif to if.
void insert_another_node(Node* root,int data){
    Node* position=root;
    Node* prePosition;
    while(position!=NULL) { 
        if (data>position->data) {
           prePosition=position;
           position=position->right;
        }
        else if (data<position->data) {
           prePosition=position;
           position=position->left;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    position=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    position->data=data;
    position->left=NULL;
    position->right=NULL;
    if (prePosition==NULL) {
        root=position;
    }
    if(data<prePosition->data) {
        prePosition->left=position;
    };
    if(data>prePosition->data) {
        prePosition->right=position;
    };
}

I have tried searched the difference between else if and if. But I think here there shouldn't have a problem because the condition is independent from each other and save the changes.
I want to know why the segment fault happened.

Node* prePosition; ==> Node *prePosition = NULL; Uninitialised variables are loose cannons. Refrain from coding them... (And I suggest you use whitespace around = and == so that the code can be read easily...) And, setting the local var root will NOT be returned to the caller for its use. Either return the pointer value, or use a double pointer (more advanced.) And, # position->left=NULL; is what? Use C's comment herald; not some other language's comment herald...

Suppose data>position->data, if you use if instead of else if, you'll change position in your first if, then use the updated value of position in the condition of second if, the second if is then certainly not checking what you meant to check, and may result in a segfault. You don't have to worry about all these if you stick to using else if whenever possible.

root=position; doesn't do what you think it will do.

If you do a bunch of else if (well orchestrated) only 1 of then will execute. You cannot say the same thing thing with a bunch of (well orchestrated) if. For example: int a = -1; if (a < 2) puts("less than 2"); /*else*/ if (a < 5) puts("less than 5"); /*else*/ puts("5 or more");

Your first bug:
    if (prePosition==NULL) {
        root=position;
    }

Doesn't do what you think it does.  It will correctly assign root to the new node that was just allocated - but only for the duration of the function. As soon as the function returns, that local variable, root is lost and doesn't change the value of root the caller passed in.  The caller won't be aware that the root changed.  Remember in C, parameters are always "by value", and that includes pointers.
The common fix is to just have the collection class take a pointer to the head of the collection so it can be changed and correctly returned to the called:
    void insert_another_node(Node** ptrRoot, int data) {
        Node* root = *ptrRoot;
        
        ...

        // handle the empty case
        if (prePosition==NULL) {
            root=position;
            *ptrRoot = position;
            return;
        }
   

Back to your if vs if-else condtion.  Consider the following code that's intending to multiple or divide a value by 10 based on another check:
if (x < 5) {
   x = x  * 10;
}
if (x > 5) {
   x = x / 10;
}

If the x is 4, then the above code path will still leave x as 4 instead of the intended value of 40.
Same thing applies to your code. So let's fix up all your code:
void insert_another_node(Node** ptrRoot, int data) {
    Node* root = *ptrRoot;
    Node* position = root;    // FIX #1 don't let this go unassigned
    Node* prePosition = NULL;
    while (position != NULL) {
        if (data > position->data) {
            prePosition = position;
            position = position->right;
        }
        else if (data < position->data) {
            prePosition = position;
            position = position->left;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }

    position = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    position->data = data;
    position->left = NULL;
    position->right = NULL;

    if (prePosition == NULL) {
        // empty case
        root = position;
        *ptrRoot = root;
    }
    else if (data < prePosition->data) {
        // assigning to left node
        prePosition->left = position;
    }
    else {
        // assigning to right node
        prePosition->right = position;
    };
}


You'd call the above code like this;
Node* root = NULL;
insert_another_node(&root, 5);  // changes root
insert_another_node(&root, 4);  // does not change root

And since you mentioned inspiration, consider this much simplified version that makes heavy use of pointer to pointer to nodes.
void insert_another_node(Node** ptrRoot, int data) {

    Node* newNode = NULL;
    
    while (*ptrRoot) {
        Node* root = *ptrRoot;

        // it seems like you want to avoid duplicates, if not, just remove this check
        if (root->data == data) {
            return;
        }
        ptrRoot = (data <= root->data) ? &root->left : &root->right; // pick left or right
    }

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->data = data;
    *ptrRoot = newNode;

}



Hi, selbie, this block is used for the situation when the tracker down the last leave so it shouldn't be this case. Thanks for the inspiration.

I'm not sure what you mean. But I've address both your bugs in my answer. And then I just amended it with a "pointer to pointer" version that simplifies the entire function based on what you've shared above.

@Fe2O3 - Good catch on the memory leak. Fixed. As for the cast, that was probably just a result of me using a C++ compiler that requires an explicit cast. OP can remove the explicit casts from malloc if they want to.  The reason I left it was <= was in case the OP removed the duplicate detection check, I wanted to be explicit about which left/right path a dupe would follow (left) instead of leaving it inferred. Pedantic stuff.

*ptrRoot = newNode; would ordinarily only happen for the very first node. // "C++ compiler"? Me, too!! :-) // <= vs. < If duplicates allowed that's "heavy left" vs "heavy right" branches. (not much difference.) // Recommend adding boilerplate warning and code to check malloc() succeeded... The world's a dangerous place! Cheers! :-)

@Fe2O3 - I'm not sure what you are saying. But I'll leave it at this. If you have a better answer, please submit it. I might even upvote it myself.

There are '000s of BST code examples in SO. The OP can go do some reading, imo, instead of glancing at a few, then writing their own and then adding their own question to the collection... Eg: "Use continue; instead of else if"... Mastery comes with patience and thought, not typing and re-typing until something gives the appearance of working... Just my opinion... Cheers! :-)

This is just about controlling the flow of the program and what happens when both ifs are evaluated which is causing this segmentation fault.
After the execution of the first if is done, the resulting position, which you check in the second if statement is now nullptr. Attempting to access this nullptr(position) will cause a segmentation fault.

After reviewing and testing, I guess the answer is once the position is nullptr when the data is bigger than the value of the prePosition, it is not out of the while loop and stay inside the loop to do the second if. Once I change the the input value all to be smaller than the previous one. It works even with "if".

Okay.... Now insert random values -- and see if it still "works". Pay close attention to the answer by @selbie.

The issue is how the root pointer is updated when a new node is inserted into the binary tree.
When you pass root to the function insert_another_node, you pass a copy of the pointer root, not the actual pointer itself. Therefore, when you update the root inside the function, the changes are not reflected outside the function.
To fix this issue, you can pass a pointer to the root pointer so that changes made to the root inside the function are reflected outside.
void insert_another_node(Node** root, int data) {
    Node* position = *root;
    Node* prePosition = NULL;

    while (position != NULL) {
        if (data > position->data) {
            prePosition = position;
            position = position->right;
        } else if (data < position->data) {
            prePosition = position;
            position = position->left;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    if (prePosition == NULL) {
        *root = newNode;
    } else if (data < prePosition->data) {
        prePosition->left = newNode;
    } else {
        prePosition->right = newNode;
    }
}

